# Rails routing error (route is defined)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web, routes

My rails application broke, it was working fine a few minutes ago. Now it gives me routing errors.

My `routes.rb` file looks like this:

```
  get "public_pages/home", :as => "home"
  get "log_in" => "sessions#new", :as => "log_in"
  get "log_out" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "log_out"
  get "sign_up" => "users#new", :as => "sign_up"
  match "session" => "sessions#create", :via =>:post
  root :to => "public_pages#home"
  resources :users, :except => [:index,
                                    :new, 
                                    :destroy]
  resources :sessions
  resources :questions
```

The error I am getting is: `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}` when I go to `localhost:3000/sign_up`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your routes look right, assuming they're actually specified in the order you're showing. Have you tried restarting the server?

Comment: Yeah, I tried restarting the server, but that did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I guess your following definitions are conflicting with each other.

```
  get "sign_up" => "users#new", :as => "sign_up"
```

with:

```
 resources :users, :except => [:index,
                                    :new, 
                                    :destroy]
```

In later one, you excluded `:new`. Probably this is overriding your earlier definition and removing that action from your routes.

Comment: I removed :new from the :except list, but the problem remains.

Comment: can you try by removing any one of the above two declarations? just for checking!